# Calling CustomDialogFragment from another CustomDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-context, android-dialog

how are you ? so i have a problem calling my custom dialog fragment (cdf) from another cdf, when i call the cdf from a FragmentActivity it works fine.
this is the method i use to call the cdf from FragmentActivity.

```
private void openDatePicker(int idView) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("VIEW", idView);
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePicker();
    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

this is the onCreate method from the first cdf

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_add, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    builder.setView(view);
```

when i called it from cdf, it gives me an error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

i am assuming it has something to do with the context, my cdf doesnt know the context of other cdf so it doesnt know what to load where. so how do i call cdf from another cdf exactly?.

Comment: It is not related to Dialog and your stack trace shows TextView issue.

Comment: @Anil i am sorry for not mentioning that the textView suppoused to be in DialogFragment A, and A sends the TextView's id through Argument, in DialogFragment B there is setText method wich setting a value for DialogFragment A's Textview. thats why i am assuming the dialog B doesnt know the context of dialog A which leads to the error.

Comment: may be your Textview is null.

Comment: @Anil i am using ButterKnife and already bind it in my onCreate method, i add the code in my question.

Comment: man it is not possible to set data from B to textview wich is in Fragment A

Comment: are you trying to access the first fragment's textview on the second fragment?

Comment: You can pass data from Fragment B and get it in Fragment A

Comment: @Anil it is possible and works in ActivityFragment like i mentioned in my question, i dont know if that is a correct way but it works. about passing data i think its the correct way but the code wouldnt be reusable for another class.

Comment: @VishnuSP exactly. it works on fragmentActivity but not in cdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing view from one fragment to another is not the correct way. The view in the 1st fragment can be destroyed when the second fragment is shown depending on whether you add/replace the fragment. [Check the fragment lifecycle here in the android doc.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Pass the value (instead of view or view id) to the second fragment as `Bundle` using `setArguements` method.

Comment: i assume so too, i just made it that way so its easy to reuse. so i guess there is no other workaround other than that?

Comment: `setArguements`is the correct approach to communicate between fragments. What workaround are you expecting? What is the issue that you facing in this approach?

Comment: i am accepting this answer because i don't think there is no correct workaround aside than this.

Comment: its not really an issue, only the code wouldnt be reusable.